# How to find relative angle from one gps coordinate vector to other?

Tags: math, angle, geo

I have extracted a set of three coordinates and I want to find the relative angles between their two vectors.

- P1: `57.3112, 25.24871`
- C1: `57.31105, 25.24875`
- T1: `57.31086, 25.24803`

Like: `V1 = C1 - P1`, `V2 = T1 - C1` and then get angle from `V1` to `V2`.

But I am afraid that cartesian functions won't cut it here, because in actual application, the coordinates could span different latitudes and longitudes.

I have searched google but the functions I have seen, do not convince me. I also tried some in my app, but the returned angles didn't return the expected results.

For these three points, deducing visually, I expect the angle to be somewhere around 120-140 degrees.

I have limited knowledge in geographic calculations and I'm out of clues here.

How do I calculate the angle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using formulas from [this page](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html), calculate bearings (azimuths) from middle point to the first one and to the third one.

```
θ = atan2( sin Δλ ⋅ cos φ2 , cos φ1 ⋅ sin φ2 − sin φ1 ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ cos Δλ )
where   φ1,λ1 is the start point, φ2,λ2 the end point (Δλ is the difference in longitude)
```

I  emphasize that for "angle to turn"  bearings should be calculated from the turn point - because for arc A-B bearings will differ in the starting and ending points (except for specific cases like meridian or parallel arcs). At the next picture direction **v** differs from direction **u** (shortest path at the sphere is so-called "big circle arc")

[image]

Having two bearings, you can get their difference to know needed angle (don't forget to treat transition over 360 degrees)

---

There is also method from spherical trigonometry - spherical cosine theorem (rearrangement part [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines)), but it requires to find arc lengths for all triangle sides (might be found using the first link - but more calculations)

Comment: Thanks! While not really grasping the whole idea behind it, this did give me enough to help me solve the problem I had!